# How do I impose restrictions $ 0\leq \alpha \leq \beta <1$?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, normalization, garch, parameterization, restrictions

I want to restrict values s.t. I get $\theta = (\alpha, \beta) =g(\theta_1, \theta_2)$
with the following restrictions.

$
0\leq \alpha \leq \beta <1
$

I know the correct answer should be $\beta = (1+\exp^{-\theta_2})^{-1}$ and $\alpha = \beta(1+\exp^{-\theta_1})^{-1}$.

However, when I make the system of equations, something goes wrong.
I assume $0\leq \alpha \leq \beta <1 \longrightarrow 0\leq \alpha \leq \beta  \ \ \& \ \  \alpha\leq \beta\leq 1 $.

So then $\begin{cases}
 \alpha = 0 + (\beta-0)(1+\exp^{\theta_1})^{-1} \\
 \beta= \alpha + (1-\alpha)(1+\exp^{\theta_2})^{-1} \\
 \end{cases}
$

is the system, and I derive the same answers as in symbolab which are definitely not following the restrictions.
Where do I go wrong in my system of equations and how do I get to the correct answer?

Comment: What are $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\theta_1$, and $\theta_2?$

Comment: $\theta_1, \theta_2$ are parameters that come out of an optimizer.
$\alpha,\beta$ are the transformed variables that I use for further analysis/inference.

Comment: Optimizer of what?

Comment: A GARCH(1,1) likelihood function, but does it matter here?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you have the "correct answer" already (the reparametrization in terms of the thetas), what do you want to know?

Comment: I want to see how I obtain the correct answer. May that be via a system of equations/intuition. Preferably strict maths though.

Comment: It's definitely through intuition, because there are multiple solutions for this problem

Comment: $0\leq \alpha \leq \beta <1 \longrightarrow 0\leq \alpha \leq \beta  \ \ \& \ \  0\leq \alpha \leq \beta$ looks repetitive.  Did you intend $0\le \alpha$ and $\alpha \le \beta$ and $\beta <1$?

Comment: @Henry oh yes, thanks